# Magento 2 Custom Theme Not Working

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I have created a custom theme and added **`Magento_Checkout`**, **`Magento_Theme, Magento_Catalog and Magento_OfflinePayments`** into it and edited some view files and both the `Magento_Checkout` & `Magento_Theme` working perfectly. I can add new files into it or edit and can see the result on the frontend but the other 2 Catalog and Offline Payments not working or getting picked up.

I checked in the `view_preprocessed` and can see `Magento_Checkout, Magento_Theme` been created but missing the other two

I run **index, cache, setup upgrade, compile**, deleted static content **redeployed** it etc

Would anyone tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: Please share your folder structure and files that you added as part of your theme module.

Comment: Hello I have created OrangeCo/orange inside app/design/frontend/. And added registration.php , composer.json and theme.xml files for the theme module. Then Magento_Checkout, Magento_Theme, Magento_Catalog and Magento_OfflinePayments created where the checkout and theme is been working but the other two are not been picked up (not showing in view_preprocessed). For example the offline payments I copied over view/frontend/web/template/payment cashondelivery.html